# Finding the maximum square sub-matrix with all equal elements

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, subset

Does anybody know how it could be possible to subset the maximum K such that K x K is a submatrix with all identical elements, i.e., all the elements in this submatrix must be the same from a given a N x N matrix?
I found many examples in other programming languages except R. I also prefer **dplyr** if you know.

There is a link to the solution with other languages:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/

But this link provides a special case when all identical elements are next to each other. It retrieves a maximum block of the same elements, not a submatrix in general. I do not want to limit subsetting with this condition.

Comment: Nice question. Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I provided the solution and examples just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following answer to this question using `dplyr`:

```
M1 <- M %>% data.frame %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(sumVar)) %>% dplyr::select(-sumVar)
M2 <- M1  %>% as.matrix %>% t %>% data.frame %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = rowSums(.)) %>% arrange(desc(sumVar)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-sumVar) %>% as.matrix %>% t %>% data.frame %>% 
  arrange_all(funs(desc(.))) 
i <- 1
j <- 1
while(sum(M2[1:i,1:j]) == i*j){
  i <- i+1
  j <- j+1
  M3 <- M2[1:i-1,1:j-1]
}
```

This is a toy data as @ThomasIsCoding proposed:

```
M <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                           5L))
```

and this is the result:

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    0    1    1    1    1
> M1
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  0  1
5  0  1  1  1  1
> M2
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  1  0
5  1  1  1  0  1
> M3
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  1
```

Note that some more functions should be added to keep the variable names and find them after using arrange!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R implementation to make it.

If you want to search the maximum square sub-matrix within a non-square matrix, you can try the code below:

```
r <- list()
for (w in rev(seq(min(dim(M))))) {
  for (rs in seq(nrow(M)-w+1)) {
    for (cs in seq(ncol(M)-w+1)) {
      mat <- M[rs-1+(1:w),cs-1+(1:w)]
      u <- unique(c(mat))
      if (all(u!=0) &length(u)==1) r[[length(r)+1]] <- mat
    }
  }
  if (length(r)>0) break
}
```

such that

```
> r
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3
```

**DATA**

```
M <- structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Dim = c(15L, 10L))

> M
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    2    2    1    1    3    2    2    1     3
 [2,]    3    2    1    3    3    1    2    3    1     3
 [3,]    1    2    3    2    3    1    2    2    2     1
 [4,]    2    3    1    2    2    2    3    1    2     1
 [5,]    1    1    3    3    3    1    2    2    2     2
 [6,]    3    3    2    3    3    1    2    1    1     2
 [7,]    3    1    2    2    2    1    3    3    1     1
 [8,]    2    1    2    2    3    1    3    3    1     2
 [9,]    2    1    2    2    3    3    3    1    2     3
[10,]    3    1    3    2    1    2    1    2    1     3
[11,]    3    2    2    1    1    1    2    1    3     3
[12,]    1    1    1    2    1    1    2    3    2     3
[13,]    1    1    3    2    1    3    1    2    3     3
[14,]    1    2    2    2    3    3    3    3    3     1
[15,]    2    2    1    2    2    3    3    3    2     3
```

**EDIT**

The approach above is inefficient when with large matrix since all combinations checked. The method below is a `R` implementation of algorithm stated in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/, which is is far more efficient.

```
M <- unname(as.matrix(read.csv(file = "test2.csv")))
S <- matrix(0,nrow = nrow(M),ncol = ncol(M))
S[,1] <- M[,1]
for (i in 1:nrow(S)) {
  for (j in 2:ncol(S)) {
    if (M[i,j]==1) {
      if (i==1) {
        S[i,j] <- M[i,j]
      } else {
        S[i,j] <- min(c(S[i,j-1],S[i-1,j],S[i-1,j-1]))+1
      }
    }
  }
}

inds <- which(S == max(S),arr.ind = TRUE)
w <- seq(max(S))-1
res <- lapply(seq(nrow(inds)), function(k) M[inds[k,"row"]-w,inds[k,"col"]-w])
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. it works very well the same as the other language version. However, I realized that this code ONLY retrieves those 1 elements which are next to each other. I need a maximum submatrix from the whole matrix with 1's that they are not necessarily next to each other. Can you help me?

Comment: @MohieddinJafari Okey, I see. Now you can check out my updates

Comment: I got this Error: Error in (l <- Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1, u))[[which.max(lengths(l))]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Comment: @MohieddinJafari sorry for my typo... should be `unique(c(x))` instead of `unique(x)`, and now it is fixed

Comment: Thanks, I think if we change `N <- dim(M)[1]` to `N <- min(dim(M))` is better

Comment: I am testing your code in this file: [link](https://gofile.io/?c=0vKneF) When I arrange the rows based on rowSums and use that as input the results is defferent. First I got 24x24 matrix but after arranging it is 48x48!

Comment: @MohieddinJafari well, of course you can use `N <- min(dim(M))`

Comment: @MohieddinJafari do you apply my code to a square matrix or matrices with different dimensions? My solution is written only for square ones...

Comment: My matrix dimension is 528*123. It is not square

Comment: @MohieddinJafari should the output sub-matrix a square one or not?

Comment: output should be square

Comment: do you access my matrix which I provided in this [link](https://gofile.io/?c=0vKneF)?The input is not square, but I need maximum square matrix as output

Comment: @MohieddinJafari You can try my newly edited solution, I guess it can give what you want

Comment: I got the memory error for assigning **lst**:  Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Comment: @MohieddinJafari I did not optimize my code for searching the max sub-matrix. I edited my solution using nested `for` loops, which would be much faster

Comment: There is something wrong, I do not what is it. but when I test this [data](https://gofile.io/?c=0vKneF), I got a list with three identical 1s matrix elements 25x25. When I check the [arranged version based on rowSums](https://gofile.io/?c=jDM2in) and use that as input the results are different: A list with three identical 0s matrix elements 66x66.

Comment: I expect to have a 1s SubMatrix >=52x52 based on manual checking in this [data](https://gofile.io/?c=0vKneF).

Comment: @MohieddinJafari did you just want the max sub matrix or the max non-zero sub matrix? you didn't state your exact objective in your post

Comment: Maximum square non zero submatrix

Comment: @MohieddinJafari I updated my solution according to your latest information. I tried my code on your data from https://gofile.io/?c=jDM2in, the size of max sub matrices are of 50 by 50

Comment: With my method, it is 88 by 88. Could you please check what does it make the difference?

Comment: @MohieddinJafari did you try to  cross check it via solutions in C++ or python from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/?

Comment: No, I didn't, I don't know programming in c++ or python

Comment: @MohieddinJafari I checked the python solution via https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/, which also gives 50-by-50 sub matrix of 1s as the max sub matrix, which is the same as achieved by my code. I have no idea what happened to your approach, since I am not very familiar with `dplyr`

Comment: @MohieddinJafari see my edits. I translate the algorithm in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/ into `R` and check the max sub matrix, and the size is 50-by-50 of all 1s when with your dataset `test2.csv`